# Show floated div with percentage width and different pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not very good with CSS, so I am posting my problem here hoping for a solution:

What I need is following:
I need an HTML row/div/line that shows a date and after the date it shows a bar which will be a percentage of the remaining screen width.

Like so:

```
2015-11-17 ---------------------(50%)
2015-11-18 ------------------------------------------- (80%)
2015-11-19 ==================================================== (100%)
```

If you will please consider in the dashes as a proper bar (like 10px height for e.g.). You might notice that 50% and 80% have `----` while 100% has `====`.

This is because for any percentage less than 100 I want the bar to be a mixed color like blue and white combo. For the 100% it will be a solid blue color bar.

I am trying to achieve this using HTML/CSS only, but I find my expertise to be lacking.

So far, I have following HTML/CSS:

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px; width:100%">
  <div style='float:left'><strong>Date </strong>{{Today.date}}</div>
  <div style='float:left;background-color:red;width:100%'></div>
</div>
```

The above code does not even show the second div with red background :(

Any pointers in helping me solve this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox could help here depending on your browser support requirements.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.date {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.bar {
  height: 10px;
  background: #f00;
}
.bar-50 {
  flex: .5;
}
.bar-80 {
  flex: .8;
}
.bar-100 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="date">2015-11-17</div>
  <div class="bar bar-50"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="date">2015-11-18</div>
  <div class="bar bar-80"></div>

</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="date">2015-11-19</div>
  <div class="bar bar-100"></div>
</div>
```

*Sneaky* version with pseudo-element instead of extra HTML

```css
.bar {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.date {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.bar::after {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  background: #f00;
}
.bar-50:after {
  flex: .5;
}
.bar-80:after {
  flex: .8;
}
.bar-100:after {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar bar-50">
  <div class="date">2015-11-17</div>
</div>

<div class="bar bar-80">
  <div class="date">2015-11-18</div>
</div>

<div class="bar bar-100">
  <div class="date">2015-11-19</div>
</div>
```

Perhaps more semantically, use a `progress` element and a label.

[**Progess Element @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="alpha">2015-11-17</label>
  <progress id="alpha" value="50" max="100">50 %</progress>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="beta">2015-11-18</label>
  <progress id="beta" value="70" max="100">70 %</progress>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="gamma">2015-11-19</label>
  <progress id="gamma" value="100" max="100">70 %</progress>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great..is this a new element? Does this have support on major browsers?

Comment: Yes, pretty new...added a reference link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px; width:100%;position: relative;">
  <div style="float: left;width: 50%;display: inline-block;"><strong>Date </strong>{{Today.date}}</div>
  <div style="float:left;width: 50%;height: 10px;display: inline-block;">
 <div class="progress" style="background-color:red;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
</div></div>
</div>
```